# How to use md-tab-group dynamicHeight property

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, angular-material2

My UI height is about 5px when displayed in a md-tab-group md-tab.

Reading  https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs > Dynamic Height > By default, the tab group will not change its height to the height of the currently active tab. To change this, set the dynamicHeight input to true. The tab body will animate its height according to the height of the active tab. How do you set dynamicHeight?

I have tried

```
class Abc{
dynamicHite = true
}

<md-tab-group [dynamicHeight]=dynamicHite>
```

but it does not work. I have tried setting it also on md-tab but the result is the same.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? For me, it's working fine.

Comment: As a matter-of-fact, when I add [dynamicHeight]=dynamicHite property, nothing is displayed. When I remove it I see the scrollable UI. Weired, but that is what I am seeing.

Comment: @developer033 Could you please show me a snippet of what works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You only need to include it as an attribute without setting its property to true, like so:

```
<md-tab-group dynamicHeight>
    <md-tab label="Profile Details"> 
        //Content1
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic property by including it in your md-tab-group tag.

```
<md-tab-group  dynamicHeight="true" >
    <md-tab label="Profile Details"> 
        //Content1
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```